# How to use Group a set of divs/web elements inside a div?

Tags: angular, pipe, grouping

I am trying to set up a Group/Ungroup functionality like Word/Excel (for selecting image). But the problem arises during the **grouping of the elements within the ngForList**. The below image(New Design) shows the output needed, after the selection of the Cards/divs

[image]

Here what I have tried is tried to reproduced with below Stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/group?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Here in that example what we need is :

[image]

1. Order by Id/ or any other columns (which fails during the grouping)
2. Grouping the Cards(which is working)

What I need is the ground equal to undefined as ordered cards. See image 2
Or

Any logic for selecting the divs,  group those selected divs, in a list.

Please help me with suggestions, documents and further example demos.

Comment: does it work with the changes I suggested?

Comment: Not yet... We need the undefined parameters ordered

Comment: Item 3 and 6 are in its own group, which is placed between Group A and B. Should item 3 be in Group A and item 6 be in Group B or should the `undefined` group (with item 3 and 6) be placed after Group B?

Comment: Item 3 and 6 doesn't belongs any group, it should be sequentially ordered like 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: So the `undefined` group should be in 2 groups?

Comment: Yes  undefined group id s  Should be added sequentially..

Comment: Please check my **edit** in my answer below (with stackblitz).

Comment: if you comment Group A of item 1, its shows some bug. Note: only for item 1.

Comment: I updated my answer again, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 groups: Group A, Group B and `undefined`. The third group `undefined` exists, because in your `array` in `app.component.ts` you did not set any `group` for the items `3` and `6`.

With the following `array` (in `app.component.ts`) it should work:

```
array = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "item 1",
      "group": "Group A"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "item 2",
      "group": "Group A"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "item 3",
      "group": "Group A" // <-- this changed
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "item 4",
      "group": "Group B"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "item 5",
      "group": "Group B"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "item 6",
      "group": "Group B" // <-- this changed
    }
  ];
```

I uncommented and edited the `group` for the items 3 and 6.

**EDIT / ADDENDUM**:

If you want your items to still be in order (1-6) but still group them, you may do the following (see also [updated stackblitz](https://group-jdw8jq.stackblitz.io)):

```js
ngOnInit(){
    this.result = [];
    var currentGroup = ''; // <-- updated this line
    this.array.forEach(item => {
      if (item.group != currentGroup) {
        currentGroup = item.group;
        this.result.push({
          name: item.group,
          values: [],
        });
      }
      this.result[this.result.length - 1].values.push(item);
    });
  }
```